# How to validate if input is only a number? intval and is_init not working

Tags: php, validation, int

I need to validate if value that user inserted in input field is only a number. The input field is for a price so only the valid numbers should be accepted from 0 to 9 and i would also avoid decimal points.

So after reading around i figured out maybe i can use `intval` to return integer of input value and later on to compare if `is_int` to see if input is only integer. I wanted to avoid `is_numeric` because that can return true for code like this `+0123.45e6`

But i have no luck, somehow it doesn't work as i intended to work. Here is my code that i am trying to validate.

```
$price = isset($_POST['price']) ? intval($_POST['price']) : '';

if( ($price != '') && (!is_int($price)) ) { // If price is correct
   $throw_error[] = __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Price must be only number.' );
   $errors = true;
   $price = '';
}
```

But somehow this fails to validate and some letters like `sdadaar` can pass the error.

Comment: All post data are strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: I know, that's why i wanted to use `intval` wouldn't `intval` convert that string into integer value?

Comment: If you cast it to an integer then it will always pass `is_int()`.

Comment: The code you posted should work. Which leads me to suspect you're not posing the entire code here, and that you're actually using `$_POST['price']` further down.

Comment: @ChristianF This is the only part of the code that is connected to the price, maybe i should mention that this is done inside WordPress but since it's just custom function in page template i don't think it has anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

All post values are strings.  You can try `is_numeric()`, or loosely (don't check type) compare the string to the string cast to an integer:

```
if($_POST['price'] != (int)$_POST['price']) {
    // error
}
```

In your current code, invalid integers / non-numeric data will be cast to the integer `0` and will always pass the `is_int()` test.

See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Hmm wait so you say, if i have `intval('sasdkosa')` it will be converted to integer value of `0` so basically that's why `is_int` is passing by error because i have a value `0`. Ill check that out now to see.

Comment: You are correct, that's why validation is not working, the `var_dump` is actually passing the value as `0` But strange thing is why this is not inserting in the database like the rest of the fields. This looks more like WordPress issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a homemade function to check if `is_int()` and don't want `is_numeric()`, try this:

```
if (strlen((int)$_POST['price']) !== strlen($_POST['price'])) echo "Not an integer";
```

Any input that is not numeric plus any floats will be truncated by (int), so their string lengths will not be equal to the string length of `$_POST['price']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['price'])) : null;        

    if($price && preg_match("#[a-z\.\-]*#i", $_POST['price']) ){
        $throw_error[] = __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Price must be only number.' );
        $errors        = true;
        $price         = '';            
    }
```

Comment: But the price can be set to 0, the point is if the price is 0 it will be marked as free item.

Comment: Alright... sure... you right... @AleksandarĐorđević

Comment: try matching for strings in the input using preg-match() @AleksandarĐorđević